# Missing Credentials while using Passport on Node JS and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, passport.js

I'm working on a project developing an API. The thing is I'm working with Passport and there's this thing that throws me an error of "Missing Credential". I've searched everywhere and I don't know what to do.

**Part of Index.js**

```
app.use(express.static(publicc));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
```

**Passport.js with the SignUp Function**

```
    passport.use('signup', new localStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true
        }, async (email, password, done) => {
            try {
                console.log('si')
                const user = await findUser(email);
                if (user.length > 0) {
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'User already exists' });
            }
            const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
            const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

            const newUser = {
                user_name: req.body.user_name,
                user_role: req.body.user_role,
                email: email,
                user_password: hashedPassword
            };

            console.log(newUser);
            const result = await createUser(newUser);
            return done(null, newUser);
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.log('si')
                done(error);
            }
        }
    ));
```

**Controller with the SingUp**

```
const postSignup = async (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('signup', { session: false }, async(err, user, info) => {
        try{
            console.log(req.body);
            if(err){
                const error = new Error('An error occurred');
                return next(error);
                }
            const message = info.message;

            if(!user){
                res.status(401).json({ success: false, message });
                return
            }

            return res.json({succes: true, message});
        }catch(error){
            return next(error);
        }
    })(req, res, next);
};
```

I already tried adding the body parsing and nothing changed. I've searched every forum but still no answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are saving email and password at DB, but you don't save salt to compare recieved password from user on sign in with that you have saved at DB.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)
You steps to auth.

1. Get user by email from database.
2. Check that hashed password that you recieved from user + salt saved at database for this user equals hashed password at your database. Or just remove salt, don't hash password (but it strongly not recommended), after it will be work, try to complicate the task and hash passwords without salt. After it will be works, try to add salt.

Look at this example how to use passport with local strategy + Express.
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/wiki/Examples

Comment: I deleted the part of salt + hash password in the signup part but still threw the missing credentials error :(.